# Find all objects in array that have time difference of 1 minute

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to find all objects where time difference between each consecutive object is less than 1 minute.

````
const input = [ 
  { id: 12,
    time: '2018-03-01T12:34:00.000Z'},
  { id: 15,
    time: '2018-03-02T09:25:20.000Z'},
  { id: 19,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:14:20.000Z'},
  { id: 23,
    time: '2018-04-01T10:24:00.000Z'},
  { id: 24,
    time: '2018-04-01T10:24:40.000Z'},
  { id: 25,
    time: '2018-04-01T10:25:10.000Z'} 
  ]

expected output ===> [ 
{ id: 23,
  time: '2018-04-01T10:24:00.000Z' },
{ id: 24,
  time: '2018-04-01T10:24:40.000Z' },
{ id: 25,
  time: '2018-04-01T10:25:10.000Z' } 
]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there's only exactly one run of consecutive items in one minute, you can use the following algorithm:

- Ensure your list is sorted, which in this case it seems is already in ascending time order, so I'll skip this step. You should not skip this step is the list isn't guaranteed to be sorted.
- We want to find the first two consecutive items. Loop through each element of the array, starting from the second. For each item:

  - Check the difference in time between the previous item and the current one. If it is less than a minute, the previous and current items are the first consecutive entries. Stop the loop (`break`).
- If we have iterated through the whole array without finding any consecutive entries, return an empty list.
- We now want to find the rest of the consecutive items. Loop through each item starting from the item directly after the last known consecutive item. For each item:

  - If the time difference between the previous and current items is more than a minute, stop the loop (`break`).
  - Otherwise, the current item is also consecutive. Count it in, and continue the loop.
- Return all known consecutive items.

Here is one such implementation:

```js
// `entries` is of type `{ id: number; time: string; }`
function getConsecutiveEntries(entries) {
  // Find the first two consecutive entries
  let idx;
  for (idx = 1; idx < entries.length; idx++) {
    const prevTime = new Date(entries[idx - 1].time).getTime();
    const curTime = new Date(entries[idx].time).getTime();
    if (curTime - prevTime <= 60000) break;
  }
  if (idx === entries.length) return [];
  const result = [entries[idx - 1], entries[idx]];

  // Find the rest of consecutive entries
  idx++;
  while (idx < entries.length) {
    const prevTime = new Date(entries[idx - 1].time).getTime();
    const curTime = new Date(entries[idx].time).getTime();
    if (curTime - prevTime > 60000) break;
    result.push(entries[idx]);
    idx++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This implementation can be further optimized by memoizing the the results of Date to number conversions (the `new Date(...).getTime()`) calls, which happens twice for most entries.